# How to check if mouse pressed and still pressed on a button in java swing app

Tags: java, swing

I have array of buttons and what I want is that when I press button and drag to another button color the path that I travel.

When I press a button it will change it's color by mousePressed method, then I drag to next button while still pressing, and will change the color of the 2nd button too. How can I do this?

This is the main class

```
public class Flowcolor extends JFrame{

    public Flowcolor(int rows,int cols,int hgap,int vgap){
        setTitle("flow color");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /**top panel in north of borderlayout
         * have two label time , number of moves
         * menue button
         */
        JPanel toppanel = new JPanel();
        add(toppanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        toppanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(toppanel,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        JTextField t1=new JTextField("Time:");
        t1.setEditable(false);  // can't write in this textfeild
        JTextField t2=new JTextField("movements number:");
        t2.setEditable(false);
        toppanel.add(t1);
        toppanel.add(t2);

        JPanel centerpanel = new JPanel();
        add(centerpanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        centerpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue,3));
        centerpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,cols));
        PosButton z[][]=new PosButton[rows+1][cols+1];

        for (int i=1;i<=rows;i++)
        {
            for (int j=1;j<=cols;j++)
            {
                PosButton btn=  new PosButton(" ",Color.DARK_GRAY,Color.lightGray);
                z[i][j]=btn;
                System.out.println(i+"  "+j);
                centerpanel.add( z[i][j]);
            }
        }
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Flowcolor z= new Flowcolor (3,3,0,0);
        //startmenu s=new startmenu();
    }
}
```

and there is posbutton class that implements mouselistener.

Comment: About the only way that this might be possible is if you were to utilise some kind of drag-n-drop into the program...

Comment: Basically, you need to know when something is dragged over the other buttons. You also need the ability to detect when a button is "dragged"

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a glass pane that detects the mouse events, but it might get tricky if you're interfering with the default behavior of the JButtons. Worth checking out though: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/09/a_wellbehaved_g.html